# Transfering CSV as a pure text table

Tags: vba, ms-access, type-conversion

I am currently using VBA script to transfer a CSV table to Access (from inside Excel)

```
objAccess.DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "", _
        "table1", "C:\donPablo\StackOverFlow\StackCSV.csv", True
```

The problem is that Access incorrectly defines Types for my columns.
Some of my columns have text and numbers rows, that's why half of the imports are damaged with an error code: "Type Conversion Failure"

I have read on the internet that you can fix that by

- Creating the table with the exact same name and with predefined types for columns

> objAccess.DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE " + cstrTable + "(id Text);"

That didn't work. The same error.

- Adding first column of type Text into the CSV file
  So I added a row which is 100% text. The same error.

It seems like there is some kind of "clever" conversion going on inside Access and I can't bypass it.
The only possible scenario to bypass this conversion would be to convert all entries inside CSV file using this logic:

Before:

> value1,value2,"value3", value4

After

> "value1","value2","value3", "value4"

Is there a way to do this operation? regex of some kind maybe?

Comment: Have you tried the import with a saved [import specification](http://www.btabdevelopment.com/ts/default.aspx?PageId=25)?

Comment: @HansUp no, didn't use any specification.. I have 15 tables and in order to create specification - I need to manually import each one of the CVS. is that correct? I hoped that there is a way to define all columns as Text without the hassle of manually importing every table..

Comment: It depends.  The import spec is not tied to a specific CSV file name or specific Access table name.  It basically maps field names and data types from source to destination.  So, if all 15 of your CSV files and all 15 tables use the same structure, you would need only one import spec.

Comment: every table have different columns with different names and values.. anyway, I have added an answer with solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

I created a hardcode solution for the above mentioned problem (no regex)

```
        Dim current_Char As Variant
        ignoretext = False

        For Counter = 1 To Len(currentLine)
            current_Char = Mid(currentLine, Counter, 1)
            next_Char = Mid(currentLine, Counter + 1, 1)

            If ignoretext = False And current_Char = """" Then 'opening of existing quote
                ignoretext = True
                newLine = newLine & current_Char
            ElseIf ignoretext = True And current_Char = """" Then 'ending of existing quote
                ignoretext = False
                newLine = newLine & current_Char
            ElseIf ignoretext = True Then
                newLine = newLine & current_Char
            ElseIf ignoretext = False Then

                If current_Char = "," Then

                    If last_Char <> """" Then
                        newLine = newLine & """"
                    End If

                    newLine = newLine & current_Char

                    If next_Char <> """" Then
                        newLine = newLine & """"
                    End If
                Else
                    newLine = newLine & current_Char
                End If
            Else
               newLine = newLine & current_Char
            End If

            last_Char = current_Char

        Next

        If Mid(currentLine, 1, 1) <> """" Then
            newLine = """" & newLine
        End If

        If Mid(currentLine, Len(currentLine), 1) <> """" Then
            newLine = newLine & """"
        End If
```

Some of the variable definitions probably missing but the logic is still there ;)

what is does basically:

before

> "fsdf, dfafs",val,",fsd",156,fsd

after

> "fsdf, dfafs","val",",fsd","156","fsd"

all of your fields are now Text type ;)

- logic ignores all the commas once existing quote is detected
- it will continue to ignore unless ending quote is found
- for all other commas logic will add a before_quote if previous Char was not a quote
- for all other commas logic will add a after_quote if next Char will not be a quote
- all other chars will be appended to string AS IS
- finally, at the end of the logic we will add quote at Start or End of string depending on existence of existing quotes at mentioned positions

have fun